# what is the meaning of "abstract representation"?

Tags: java, file, io

in java.io.File 
it says:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

what do abstract mean in this case?, why not 
say

> A representation of file and directory pathnames.

a lot of classes contain this word tell now i don't understand what does it stand for ... can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about semantics and not programming.

Comment: but this place is for java or ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html for a quick lesson on abstract classes.

Comment: @DM "Abstract" in this case has nothing to do with abstract classes, that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @lexicore oops, my bad.

Comment: @Kayaman I disagree. If documentation says "abstract" on a non-abstract class, it is a legitimate question.

Comment: @lexicore A legitimate question sure, for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

> An **abstract representation** of file and directory pathnames. 
>   User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent pathname strings
>   to name files and directories. This class ***presents an*** abstract,
>   system-independent ***view*** of hierarchical pathnames.

This just means that, java will give you a pathname, that you can work with. It doesn't need to be the actual/exact pathname that the UI or OS uses. Hence it is "abstract", because it doesn't exist, it's something that java has made, to show 
 you in a presentable form.
More precisely,
the class presents a view, which is abstract and system-independent of pathnames.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Read on:

> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent *pathname strings* to name files and directories.  This class presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames.

*Abstract* in this case has nothing to do with [abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), it merely says that this representation is a view of hierarchical pathnames which is not specific to a certain operating system. An opposite would be an system-specific implementation.

Comment: ty now i understand what it does

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily that it's not a specific implementation; after all, `java.util.List` isn't described as an *abstract representation*. I think it is that it's not the *object itself* (the file in the file system), but rather a placeholder to represent that, designed in a way that isn't tied to the way a particular OS represents files.

Answer (score 0):

This use of the word "abstract" is different to the more common usage in Java (`abstract`, denoting that a method or some methods are left unimplemented).

In this case, *abstract* is meant in the more widely-understood (outside of Java) case, which is that it hides details. There is a nice quote on [the Wikipedia page about abstraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)):

> The essence of abstractions is preserving information that is relevant in a given context, and forgetting information that is irrelevant in that context.
>
> – John V. Guttag

In a sense, everything in Java is an abstraction, and so the use of the word "abstract" here is perhaps superfluous. But then, everything is also a "representation"; so that word arguably unnecessary too.

(It's also important to notice that this definition of abstraction doesn't imply `abstract`: your abstraction can have a concrete implementation).

I think that there are a couple of points that the author is trying to convey that *things you might want are hidden*: the class is designed to allow you to do "the common things" that you want to do to a file; but you might not be able to access the property that you want, and you know is available on your OS. That's just a design choice of using a language intended to run on all platforms.